# Improve db4o linq query

Tags: linq, performance, db4o

I got a problem with this linq query:

```
from PersistedFileInfo fi in m_Database
from PersistedCommit commit in m_Database
where commit.FileIDs.Contains( fi.ID )
where fi.Path == <given path>
select new Commit( m_Storage, commit );
```

As you can see, every `PersistedCommit` contains a `Collection<int>` called `FileIDs` which connects it to its `PersistedFileInfo`s. I want to select all previous commits of a specific fileInfo (which is identified by its path).

I have about 800 `PersistedFileInfo`s and 10 `PersistedCommit`s. The query takes about 1.5 seconds - which is in my opition far too long. The contructor of the `Commit`-object saves only the two given arguments - so there is no timeloss, here.

My question:
Can this query be rewritten to perform better - or is it a db4o problem (use a SODA query instead)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if your NQ is indeed optimized ([see here](http://developer.db4o.com/Resources/view.aspx/Reference/Tuning/Diagnostics/NativeQueryNotOptimized)). If not then your best bet is to translate this into SODA query yourself.

Goran